# Where can I ask a question about Amazon AWS free tier?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Is there any Stack Exchange site where this question of mine would be topical? - [AWS free tier account with credit card - is it possible to make sure nothing is charged?](https://superuser.com/questions/1655027/aws-free-tier-account-with-credit-card-is-it-possible-to-make-sure-nothing-is)

Super User closed it as off-topic.

My question is about if it's possible on AWS free tier to avoid charges if you cross the free tier limits - will AWS charge your credit card or is there a way to set it so that your account gets locked rather than your credit being charged?

Comment: This seems like a question you'd have to ask AWS.

Comment: In case you didn't know, they have a [forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://money.stackexchange.com/q/56116

Answer (score 2):

DevOps Stack Exchange has some questions about [billing in AWS](https://devops.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Baws%5D+billing). Most of them aren't too well received, but it might be worth a try. Their [Help Center](https://devops.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) isn't really helpful in determining whether this question is on-topic or not, but to me (not a regular there) it looks like a practical problem you could be facing as a DevOps engineer. Please do include some research about what you already found (but didn't help); this increases the chance you'll get a useful answer.

Comment: In addition to that, you might want to post on the per-site meta first.

Comment: The corresponding meta site may or may not contain more detailed information than the Help Center.